# How using CSS change HTML title

Tags: html, css

I have `<tr class="task"title="Edit">`
How can I transfer title to css class like this

```
tr.task{
title="Edit";
}
```

Comment: Not really clear on what you want to achieve

Comment: CSS is for styling... not for storing attribute data?

Comment: You cannot set HTML attributes using CSS.

Comment: I have many places where I use "task" style class and I have Title title="@Shop.Resources.Properties.Literals.Edit" I want to transfer this big string to css class. It's possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use jQuery to change the title property.

```
$('.task').prop('title', 'your new title');
```

Or the title attribute:

```
$('.task').attr('title', 'your new title');
```

Read about the differences here: [.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)

Comment: Maybe you know, how I can transmit not 
 $('.task-row-link').attr('title', 'Edit');
but
$('.task-row-link').attr('title', '@Shop.Resources.Properties.Literals.Edit');

Comment: You should be able to add that title using the way described. See JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/jamesbr139/3xj6b4sw/

Answer (score 0):

It is beyond the capabilities of CSS to change title, but if you're looking to select `tr.task` with the title "Edit", here's how you can do that using [attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

> tr.task[title="Edit"]